# Can we add a dot separated A record in bind?

Tags: dns, bind

Is this a correct way to add a Host resource A record in Bind

```
zone example.com

$TTL 900
@       IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
                            2017102300   ; serial number
                            3600         ; refresh
                            600          ; retry
                            86400        ; expire
                            3600       ) ; minimum TTL

@                       NS      ns1.example.com.

foo.bar       IN        A       192.168.0.1
```

I know this works well and resolves in public DNS however however question is since bar.example.com becomes a subdomain so foo's  host record should be part of bar.example.com zone

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but this looks like a pretty straightforward configuration to me. Even there is no record for bar.example.com everything is okay. Unless if by "part of bar.example.com zone" you mean there is a zone file for bar.example.com, in this case this record will not work, but it does not make it wrongly created.

Source: Years of practice :)